# Cross compilation: more difficult than it should be?

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, cross-compiling

I am wondering one thing that is quite time-consuming when coding with C/C++ for different architectures and OSes, such as Android and Iphone.

I see that every gcc based compiler must be compiled with:

1. target
2. build
3. host

I wonder if it would be **technically possible** and **technically feasible** to have *a single compiler binary* that can generate code for all the targets, as long as the cross compiled libraries exist. It would be configurable with a flag or set of flags.

Comment: can't you just script this?

Comment: Noone will save you from having to install all the cross compilers, it's different names, etc. It could be done, but not a task for the beginner.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible but not supported by most compilers. There is a project called ELLCC that is trying to build a multi-target cross compilation environment for embedded systems which makes use of Clang and the LLVM compiler infrastructure.

Comment: Very interesting project. How mature is it? This would save some headaches, definitely.

Comment: ELLCC is coming along but is hardly mature. It does target ARM, Microblaze, Mips, PowerPC, and X86 targets using one compiler (based on clang/LLVM) and a set of binutils that are configured to support all the targets. It recently reached the milestone of being able to build itself. http://ellcc.org/blog/?p=251